# Rails:-Using the Angel List API to find startups based on location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api

Has anyone had any luck using the Angel List API to return a list of startups based on location?  I noticed the startup hash does seem to contain some sort of location hash.  Got this from the Rails console:

```
irb(main):017:0> hiring = AngellistApi.all_startups(:filter => :hiring)
irb(main):037:0> hiring.each do |company|
irb(main):038:1* puts company[:name], company[:locations]
irb(main):039:1> end
IFTTT
#<Hashie::Mash angellist_url="https://angel.co/san-francisco" display_name="San Francisco" id=1692 name="san francisco" tag_type="LocationTag">
Twice 

#<Hashie::Mash angellist_url="https://angel.co/san-francisco" display_name="San Francisco" id=1692 name="san francisco" tag_type="LocationTag">
Assembly
#<Hashie::Mash angellist_url="https://angel.co/san-francisco" display_name="San Francisco" id=1692 name="san francisco" tag_type="LocationTag">
Captricity
#<Hashie::Mash angellist_url="https://angel.co/berkeley" display_name="Berkeley" id=1697 name="berkeley" tag_type="LocationTag">
etc.
```

Comment: Why dont you make it, `puts company[:name], company[:locations].display_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesome!  That means I can do something like this:

```
irb(main):021:0> hiring.each do |company|
irb(main):022:1*   company[:locations].each do |location|
irb(main):023:2*     if location.name == "london"
irb(main):024:3>       puts company[:name]
irb(main):025:3>     end
irb(main):026:2>   end
irb(main):027:1> end
Geckoboard
```

Comment: Yes sir, you could do that. Though, if you want to be more rubyish, you could refactor your if statement to use this instead:
    puts company[:name] if location.name == "london"

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently working with AngellistApi as well. If you check out the API documentation for the module (Startups) of the method (.all_startups) that you're using, it returns hashes and arrays of hashes as well. See: [Angel List API Spec for Startups](https://angel.co/api/spec/startups). For example, "markets" returns an array of two hashes.

In your case, to get the location of the startup, you could either assume that there's only one location (not the best method) and do:

```
puts company[:name], company[:locations].first.name
```

OR a better way would be to get all locations using a loop.

```
company[:locations].each { |location| puts location.name }
```

Use either one pending on the goal of your app. Good luck!